# "volatile" qualifier and compiler reorderings

Tags: c++, c, volatile, compiler-optimization

A compiler cannot eliminate or reorder reads/writes to a `volatile`-qualified variables.

But what about the cases where other variables are present, which may or may not be `volatile`-qualified?

### Scenario 1

```
volatile int a;
volatile int b;

a = 1;
b = 2;
a = 3;
b = 4;
```

Can the compiler reorder first and the second, or third and the fourth assignments?

### Scenario 2

```
volatile int a;
int b, c;

b = 1;
a = 1;
c = b;
a = 3;
```

Same question, can the compiler reorder first and the second, or third and the fourth assignments?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The C++ standard says (1.9/6):

> The observable behavior of the
>   abstract machine is its sequence of
>   reads and writes to volatile data and
>   calls to library I/O functions.

In scenario 1, either of the changes you propose changes the sequence of writes to volatile data.

In scenario 2, neither change you propose changes the sequence. So they're allowed under the "as-if" rule (1.9/1):

> ... conforming implementations are
>   required to emulate (only) the
>   observable behavior of the abstract
>   machine ...

In order to tell that this has happened, you would need to examine the machine code, use a debugger, or provoke undefined or unspecified behavior whose result you happen to know on your implementation. For example, an implementation might make guarantees about the view that concurrently-executing threads have of the same memory, but that's outside the scope of the C++ standard. So while the standard might permit a particular code transformation, a particular implementation could rule it out, on grounds that it doesn't know whether or not your code is going to run in a multi-threaded program.

If you were to use observable behavior to test whether the re-ordering has happened or not (for example, printing the values of variables in the above code), then of course it would not be allowed by the standard.

Comment: Why does the reordering in 2.1 change the sequence? Only one assignment is to a volatile variable?

Comment: Glad somebody understands `volatile` +1

Comment: machine code is not enough, because it says nothing on how an OOO processor will actually execute things. to control order, hardware memory barriers must also be used (using intrinsics or assembly). And to better control compilation ordering, compiler specific read/write barriers can be used (only intrinsics). `volatile` definition is `not optimize out read and writes` (on the assumption of no visible side effects). Its better not to rely on anything about ordering wrt volatile, its not about that, its about code elimination.

Comment: @v.oddou: If you observe re-ordering in the machine code, then the compiler has re-ordered. You're right that you can't necessarily say that there's *no* re-ordering just because it's *not* obvious from the instructions, but I was talking about confirming that re-ordering has happened, I wasn't talking about confirming that it hasn't. And then, regardless of whether the writes are re-ordered or not, in the absence of memory barriers they might be observed in another thread to occur in a different order from which they were made, depending on cache architecture.

Answer (score 4):

For scenario 1, the compiler should not perform any of the reorderings you mention.  For scenario 2, the answer might depend on:

- and whether the `b` and `c` variables are visible outside the current function (either by being non-local or having had their address passed
- who you talk to (apparently there is some disagreement about how string `volatile` is in C/C++)
- your compiler implementation

So (softening my first answer), I'd say that if you're depending on certain behavior in scenario 2, you'd have to treat it as non-portable code whose behavior on a particular platform would have be determined by whatever the implementation's documentation might indicate (and if the docs said nothing about it, then you're out of luck with a guaranteed behavior.

from C99 5.1.2.3/2 "Program execution":

> Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function that does any of those operations are all side effects, which are changes in the state of the  execution  environment.  Evaluation  of  an  expression  may  produce  side  effects.  At certain specified points in the execution sequence called sequence points, all side effects of previous evaluations shall be complete and no side effects of subsequent evaluations shall have taken place.
>
> ...
>
> (paragraph 5) The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:
>
> - At sequence points, volatile objects are stable in the sense that previous accesses are complete and subsequent accesses have not yet occurred.

Here's a little of what Herb Sutter has to say about the required behavior of `volatile` accesses in C/C++ (from "`volatile` vs. `volatile`" http://www.ddj.com/hpc-high-performance-computing/212701484) :

> what about nearby ordinary reads and writes -- can those still be reordered around unoptimizable reads and writes? Today, there is no practical portable answer because C/C++ compiler implementations vary widely and aren't likely to converge anytime soon. For example, one interpretation of the C++ Standard holds that ordinary reads can move freely in either direction across a C/C++ volatile read or write, but that an ordinary write cannot move at all across a C/C++ volatile read or write -- which would make C/C++ volatile both less restrictive and more restrictive, respectively, than an ordered atomic. Some compiler vendors support that interpretation; others don't optimize across volatile reads or writes at all; and still others have their own preferred semantics.

And for what it's worth, Microsoft documents the following for the C/C++ `volatile` keyword (as Microsoft-sepcific):

> - A write to a volatile object (volatile write) has Release semantics; a reference to a global or static object that occurs before a write to a volatile object in the instruction sequence will occur before that volatile write in the compiled binary.
> - A read of a volatile object (volatile read) has Acquire semantics; a reference to a global or static object that occurs after a read of volatile memory in the instruction sequence will occur after that volatile read in the compiled binary.
>
> This allows volatile objects to be used for memory locks and releases in multithreaded applications.

Comment: As observed from the same thread.  The standard doesn't say anything about when the changes can be visible to other tasks.  But even the quote you give in your answer says that _volatile_ objects are stable, there are no guarantees concerning other, non-volatile, accesses.

Comment: Volatile objects are stable; it is not the case that all objects are stable when a volatile object is accessed.

Comment: My interpretation of the first paragraph is that only the first case is ruled out. It says "all side effects of previous evaluations shall be complete", but does not mention "non-side-effects": local non-volatile variables reads/writes, which is not considered side effects according to this definition.

Comment: At the sequence point which follows `c = b`, the side effect of `c = b` must be complete, *in the abstract machine*, but this is still subject to the "as-if" rule. Whether `c` has actually been assigned or not in the emitted machine code is not observable behavior in the example code, so an implementation is free to reorder it (or eliminate it entirely, since `c` is unused). If there were a function call to unknown code that might have a reference to `c`, after `c = b` but before `a = 3`, then the value of `c` "at that sequence point" potentially affects observable behavior.

Comment: Regarding your edit: it gets a bit more exciting if the implementation supports threading as an extension, and wants to use `volatile` as part of its multi-threaded memory model, which is what Microsoft does. C++03 of course doesn't care about any of that. I'm curious to know whether Sutter reads the standard to permit `c` to be optimized away entirely, but not to permit the write to it to be reordered across the write to `a`. If so, what's the point? If not is he saying `c` can't be omitted? Or that his interpretation doesn't apply to this case for some reason.

Comment: Based on feedback, I've softened my answer regarding scenario 2.

Answer (score 2):

Volatile is not a memory fence. Assignments to B and C in snippet #2 can be eliminated or performed whenever. Why would you want the declarations in #2 to cause the behavior of #1?

Comment: There is a very common pattern where code needs to write to a bunch of variables and then set a "ready" flag, or where it needs to read a bunch of variables after having observed a "ready" flag. Having an access to a `volatile` flag act as a memory fence would eliminate the need to make all of the other variables `volatile`, and thus allow a compiler to reorder or coalesce accesses to those variables.  Better yet would be a "semi-volatile" qualifier which would make accesses to a variable ordered with respect to volatiles but not other semi-volatiles, but the Standard doesn't include that.

Comment: @supercat The C++ standard has something even better in `std::atomic`. I'm not sure about C11 `_Atomic`, but it likely does offer a memory fence.

Comment: From what I could make out, the Standard doesn't really make clear the relationship between the compiler and the execution platform.  Especially in free-standing implementations, the programmer may know more about the memory-interface configuration than the compiler, and as a consequence the compiler might not know what's necessary to create effective memory fences in various scenarios with multiple CPUs, DMA, etc. but the programmer may know what's needed to ensure that the effects of executed loads and stores hit physical memory when they need to *if* it's possible to ensure that the...

Comment: ...loads and stores get executed in the first place.  Supporting _Atomic types effectively may be difficult for free-standing implementations, but useful load-store-level semantics shouldn't be.  Unfortunately, even though every platform should be able to offer a load-store-level memory barriers effectively, the Standard doesn't mandate any such thing, and some compilers interpret the type-aliasing rule in such a way that it's possible for a single-threaded program that uses internal memory management to recycle blocks of memory as different types can manage to...

Comment: ...lose data races *with itself* [e.g. if memory gets recycled as a lazy-clear hash table (which reads uninitialized data but is will work correctly if such reads yield any value) after having been used as some other type, aggressive compilers may decide that since reading as a hash table entry after writing as that other type would be UB, the compiler can reorder writes of the other types after hash-table writes that are preceded by reads of the same slots.].  Memory fences would block such nonsense, but the C Standard doesn't include any that can even handle the single-threaded cases.

Answer (score 0):

Some compilers regard accesses to volatile-qualified objects as a memory fence.  Others do not.  Some programs are written to require that `volatile` works as a fence.  Others aren't.

Code which is written to require fences, running on platforms that provide them, may run better than code which is written to not require fences, running on platforms that don't provide them, but code which requires fences will malfunction if they are not provided.  Code which doesn't require fences will often run slower on platforms that provide them than would code which does require the fences, and implementations which provide fences will run such code more slowly than those that don't.

A good approach may be to define a macro `semi_volatile` as expanding to nothing on systems where `volatile` implies a memory fence, or to `volatile` on systems where it doesn't.  If variables that need to have accesses ordered with respect to other `volatile` variables but not to each other are qualified as `semi-volatile`, and that macro is defined correctly, reliable operation will be achieved on systems with or without memory fences, and the most efficient operation that can be achieved on systems with fences will be achieved.  If a compiler actually implements a qualifier that works as required, `semivolatile`, it could be defined as a macro that uses that qualifier and achieve even better code.

IMHO, that's an area the Standard really should address, since the concepts involved are applicable on many platforms, and any platform where fences aren't meaningful can simply ignore them.