# Why gcc isn't optimizing the global variable?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, optimization, volatile

I am trying to understand the behavior of `volatile` and compiler optimization in C through an example.

For this, I referred:

[Where to use volatile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3649372/2805824)

[Why is volatile needed in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/246127/2805824)

https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming

All of the above posts have at least one answer related to signal handler so for this, I have written a simple code to actually implement and observe the behavior in Linux just for understanding.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int counter = 0;

void *thread0_func(void *arg)
{
    printf("Thread 0\n");
    while(1)
    {

    }
    return NULL;
}

void *thread1_func(void *arg)
{
    printf("Thread 1\n");
    while(counter == 0)
    {
        printf("Counter: %d\n", counter);
        usleep(90000);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void action_handler(int sig_no)
{
    printf("SigINT Generated: %d\n",counter);
    counter += 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_t thread_id[2];

    struct sigaction sa;

    sa.sa_handler = action_handler;

    if(sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL))
        perror("Cannot Install Sig handler");


    if(pthread_create(&thread_id[0], NULL, thread0_func, NULL))
    {
        perror("Error Creating Thread 0");
    }
    if(pthread_create(&thread_id[1], NULL, thread1_func, NULL))
    {
        perror("Error Creating Thread 0");
    }
    else
    {

    }
    while(1)
    {
        if(counter >= 5)
        {
            printf("Value of Counter is more than five\n");
        }
        usleep(90000);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

This code is just for learning and understanding.

I tried compiling the code using:
`gcc -O3 main.c -o main -pthread`

But the compiler is not acting on global variable `counter` and is not optimizing it.
I was expecting `*thread1_func` to execute in a forever loop and the `if (counter >= 5)` to be never true.

What am I missing here?

GCC Version: `gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)`

Comment: The program has undefined behaviour if `action_handler` is actually executes.

Comment: And Why is it so?

Comment: You are modifying `counter` while accessing it from another thread. This is not allowed.

Comment: So, the solution is to declare it volatile?

Comment: If you didn't have threads, you could declare it `volatile sig_atomic_t`. With threads it is not guaranteed to work, you need an actual synchronisation mechanism (mutex, semaphore or similar). I'm not sure you can use them from a signal handler though.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575106/posix-threads-and-signals) for info about working with threads and signals at the same time. If you have a signal signal-handling thread, you can use a volatile sig_atomic_t variable to pass info from the signal handler to the thread working loop.

Comment: @n.m. I got your point. Using a synchronization mechanism will ensure that thread should not read the value when the signal handler is modifying it. Right?

Comment: It is actually not recommended to use thread synchronisation from signal handlers. See comments above.

Comment: All right. Thanks for the insights and for the link too!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your if tests on the value of `counter` are interspersed with calls to `usleep` and `printf`. These are opaque library calls. The compiler cannot see through them and so it has to assume they may have access to the `counter` external variable, and so it has to reload the `counter` variable after those calls.

If you move these calls out, the code gets optimized as you expect:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int counter = 0;

void *thread0_func(void *arg)
{
    printf("Thread 0\n");
    while(1)
    {

    }
    return NULL;
}

void *thread1_func(void *arg)
{
    printf("Thread 1\n");
    unsigned i=0;
    while(counter == 0)
    {
       i++;
    }
    printf("Thread 1: %d, i=%u\n", counter, i);
    return NULL;
}

void action_handler(int sig_no)
{
    printf("SigINT Generated: %d\n",counter);
    counter += 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_t thread_id[2];

    struct sigaction sa;

    sa.sa_handler = action_handler;

    if(sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL))
        perror("Cannot Install Sig handler");


    if(pthread_create(&thread_id[0], NULL, thread0_func, NULL))
    {
        perror("Error Creating Thread 0");
    }
    if(pthread_create(&thread_id[1], NULL, thread1_func, NULL))
    {
        perror("Error Creating Thread 0");
    }
    else
    {

    }
    while(1)
    {
        if(counter >= 5)
        {
            printf("Value of Counter is more than five\n");
        }
        usleep(90000);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Even if you make the counter variable `static`, the compiler will still not optimize, because although an external library definitely won't see the counter variable, the external call may theoretically have a mutex lock, which would allow another thread to change the variable without a data race. Now neither `usleep` nor `printf` are wrappers around a mutex lock, but the compiler doesn't know, nor does it do inter-thread optimization, so it has to be conservative and reload the counter variable after the call and the reload is what prevents the optimization you expect.

Of course, a simple explanation would be that your program is undefined if the signal handler executes, because you should've made `counter` `volatile sig_atomic_t` and you should've have synced your inter-thread access to it with either `_Atomic` or a mutex -- and in an undefined program, anything is possible.

Comment: C and its compilers are really mysterious!!

@PSkocik Thanks!!