# Why I can't escape in this while loop in Release mode?

Tags: c++, multithreading

There is a function that changes the value "bIsTrue" to true after 2sec.
When bIsTrue is "true", the main thread can escape while loop and print out "Now bIsTrue is True!" in main()

```
#include <iostream>

#include <process.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

bool bIsTrue; // global variable
unsigned __stdcall Func(void* pArg)
{
    Sleep(2000);
    bIsTrue = true;
    
    return 0;
}
```

and this is main().
but when there is nothing in while loop,
the main thread do not print "Now bIsTrue is True!" in release mode.

```
int main()
{
    // bIsTrue will be "true" after 2sec.
    bIsTrue = false;
    HANDLE tHandle = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, Func, NULL, 0, NULL);
    CloseHandle(tHandle);

    size_t i = 0;
    while (!bIsTrue)
    {
        // If here is a nothing, main thread can't escape this loop in Release mode.
        // but can escape in Debug mode.

        // When here is Sleep() or cout, main thread can escape this loop in both mode.
        // Sleep(1000);
        // OR
        // cout << i++ << endl;
    }

    cout << "Now bIsTrue is True!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

this is the result when print 'i' in the loop.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UHEW.png)

Can you guys understand why I got this result?

Comment: Isn't an infinite loop Undefined Behavior?

Comment: Why are you closeHandle-ing? Does that stop the thread? I would suggest using C++ cross-platform thread utilities.

Comment: drescherjm // But adding Sleep or court is also still infinite loop. isn't it?

Comment: Sometimes with UB a little change has a drastic change in behavior.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41320725/is-infinite-loop-still-undefined-behavior-in-c-if-it-calls-shared-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41320725/is-infinite-loop-still-undefined-behavior-in-c-if-it-calls-shared-library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What may be happening is that your flag variable is being optimized out by the compiler because it think it can't change. Here is a case you could use `volatile`, and also `std::atomic`:

```
volatile std::atomic<bool> bIsTrue = false;
```

Also, I would check your use of WinAPI functions. I would suggest instead using the standard C++ thread library: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/thread .

Comment: Thank you! a compiler optimization was the problem.. and _beginthreadex is for my Windows game programming. thank you.

Comment: Note that `volatile` is *not* actually what helps you in this case. It's `std::atomic` that alerts the compiler that the variable's reads and writes must be serializable between threads, and thus prevents it from optimizing out the read in the while loop. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26307071/does-the-c-volatile-keyword-introduce-a-memory-fence

Comment: Edward // I appreciate it!